# LinkPresentation not displaying thumbnail URL

Tags: swift

Whenever using LinkPresentation / LPLinkView and a link has og:type in the metadata, the link preview image does not show. Is there any way to get around this?

**With og:type:**

[image: github]

**Without og:type**

[image: whatsapp]